# Please explain to layman — OCC Memo 50218, dated March 22 2022 — on VanEck Russia ETF (RSX) options?

Tags: options, russia

I bought put options on RSX  that shall expire April 1 2022. Obviously, I want to sell them for cash through my discount broker, Questrade, as soon as possible!

I fail to understand anything in https://infomemo.theocc.com/infomemos?number=50218. Please simplify it. **Does OCC Memo 50218 mean that after March 22 2022, I can sell my April 1 2022 RSX put options for cash through my discount broker Questrade** — ***normally,  like before RSX stopped trading***?

> Date: March 22, 2022
>
> Subject: VanEck Russia ETF - Settlement Update
> Option Symbol: RSX
>
> - - - Effective Immediately * * *
>
> Effective March 16, 2022, the National Securities Clearing Corporation (“NSCC”) no longer accepted RSX
> exercise and assignment activity for settlement. As a result all exercise and assignment activity for RSX
> options beginning March 16, 2022 were subject to broker to broker settlement, as stated in OCC Information
> Memos #50188 and #50208. **OCC was informed that RSX shares are CNS eligible. As a result, all exercise
> and assignment activity for RSX options from March 22, 2022 and after, will no longer be subject to broker
> to broker settlement. Exercise and assignment activity for RSX options will settle through NSCC.**
>
> **Exercise and assignment activity for RSX options between March 16, 2022 and March 21, 2022, will remain
> subject to broker to broker settlement.**
>
> **The deliverable for RSX options will remain the underlying 100 VanEck Russia ETF (RSX) shares.**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSCC, which clears securities trades, was previously not settling options for a little while.

NSCC has reversed course on this, so broker-to-broker settlement (which is what was used before) is no longer being used.

It's a settlements thing mostly and just means that RSX option exercises will be settled how they normally are